# can access vuejs v-model when include laravel page

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

hi im using `vuejs` and `laravel` this is my `vuejs` code

```
Vue.component('search_and_select',{
    template:
    '<div>'+
        '<slot :test_text="test_text" :update_test_text="update_test_text"></slot>

    '</div>',
    data:function(){
        return {
            test_text:null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
     update_test_text(value) {
       this.test_text = value
     }
   }
});
```

and this is html code

```
<search_and_select>
  <div slot-scope="{ test_text, update_test_text }">
    <input
      type="text"
      :value="test_text"
      @input="update_test_text($event.target.value)"
    >
  </div>
</search_and_select>
```

like this everything working so good so far .. 
but if i tried to include page like this ..

```
@include('treats.text_values') // laravel blade
```

and inside `treats.text_values` i did this ..

```
<input
  type="text"
  :value="test_text"
  @input="update_test_text($event.target.value)"
>
```

its not working so how can i access vuejs using include in laravel .. 
thanks a lot

Comment: you have to mount your compoent to any `id` of blade

Comment: What do you mean with not working? It seems to work on my side.

Comment: its not working if i inspect element i gat it like this <input
  type="text"
  :value="test_text"
  @input="update_test_text($event.target.value)"
> and its should be like this <input  type="text">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all as @Kamlesh Paul said be sure your component is between your id or el in your app probably its #app and second of all if you cp and paste your code you'r missed a "'" in your template it should be like this:

```
Vue.component('search_and_select',{
    template:
    '<div>'+
        '<slot :test_text="test_text" :update_test_text="update_test_text"></slot>' +

    '</div>',
    data:function(){
        return {
            test_text:null,
        }
    },
    methods: {
     update_test_text(value) {
       this.test_text = value
     }
   }
});
```